# How to make auto-complete work for AWS on ZSH?

Tags: macos, homebrew, iterm, zsh, command-line

I installed awscli from brew.

The [amazon instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-completion.html) refer to a shell script, `aws_zsh_completer.sh` that doesn't appear to be included.   I do have an `/usr/local/bin/aws_completer`.

How do I make the autocompleter for `aws` work on `zsh` in `iTerm2` on `macos Catalina`?

Comment: Ugh - I got it working but can't get my .zshrc quite right yet. My answer is incomplete so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK - completions need a [bit of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273395/how-to-enable-command-completion-for-azure-cli-in-zsh) to get going - brew includes the definitions, but you have to [prime the completions mechanism](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296477/my-command-line-says-complete13-command-not-found-compdef) if you haven't enabled one yet.

```
brew install zsh-completions
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Press `y` when asked to ignore insecure directories

Then to test things out run the initialization:

```
autoload bashcompinit && bashcompinit
source /usr/local/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh
```

I know - it says bash and you use zsh - you can type aws followed by a space and gla and tab and it should pause a bit and complete to the glacier command instead of file completion:

```
aws gla
```

Once that's set, you have to set up your .zshrc and likely fix the [insecure compinit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753363/475228) error by removing write permissions on some directories.

Comment: It works in the current shell after the first stanza (down to compinit) but there is no `/usr/local/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh` file.  Not sure how to make it stick.. put autoload && compinit in the zshrc?  Meanwhile compinit wants me to remove write to /usr/local/share from the admin group?!

Comment: @John2095 yeah. It’s a mess. The insecure compinit link fixed the share perms for me.

Answer (score 12):

I know this question is kinda old but there's a better answer if you're running awscli 2.1 or greater **and** are using oh-my-zsh. Basically, to confirm this solution run this command from your zsh shell

`complete -C aws_completer aws`

Then you can test to make sure the completion works by typing partial aws command like `aws s3` and pressing tab.

If this works then you can add the `complete -C aws_completer aws` to you `.zshrc` startup profile.  I got this from the [following article:](https://ig.nore.me/2020/02/the-new-and-improved-aws-cli-v2/)

Comment: I'm not running OMZ, but when I run `complete...` in the shell, autocomplete starts working. But when I put the identical command in my `.zshrc` and start a new shell, no autocomplete. Confusing.